# Is it recommended to set Ember.testing = true for unit tests?

Tags: ember.js

We've recently started to use the undocumented Ember.testing flag in our jasmine specs which effectively disables the autorun runloop feature. We've found that this requires us to be quite a bit more explicit about manually wrapping code in runloops but has also given us more stability in our specs as it highlights problems in the way we've written the spec and helps to document when bindings are important to the code under test.

Is there an official line on the usage of this feature ?  It appears to have had quite a positive impact in our app but I suspect most people aren't aware of it.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you should definitely set `Ember.testing = true` in your tests.

Without `Ember.testing`, runloops are scheduled automatically with `setTimeout`, which is where the instability you're noting comes from.

Note: At the moment, when you activate `Ember.testing`, you necessarily end up prefixing many of the lines in your test code with `Em.run =>`, like

```
Em.run => obj.set('someProperty', true)
```

If you forget to, it will complain loudly, or properties/app state won't have updated when you try to run assertions against it.

Maybe this will be improved some day, but for now it's nothing to be worried about if your test code is sprinkled with `run` calls.

Answer (score -1):

I've never used the `Ember.testing` flag. I'd be interested to hear how enabling it has resulted in more stability in your specs. I've been testing Ember apps in Jasmine without any issues.

I've had success following the Ember test suite's usage of `Ember.run()` and `Ember.run.sync()` when necessary.

Comment: The stability seemed to come mainly from developers being forced to think about the run loop, how it relates to the code that is running and the assertions being made on that code. A great deal of the Ember internals rely on there being a current run loop or they throw an exception so by not having an autorun runloop, it's easy to see where a spec should be wrapping calls to application code.

Comment: We had a number of intermittent failures due to specs that sometimes passed in places where I think that they should have failed consistently. Setting Ember.testing = true ensured that these specs always failed.